# Removing icon buttons from DualListField

Tags: layout, gxt, multi-select

In GWT application, I am using the DualListField which has six icon buttons(arrows) associated with it?

Our requirement is to use only the left and right arrows.

But the widget is created in the constructor of DualListField so I am not able to disable those arrows as well as the buttons are defined as private without any getters and setters.We are using GXT 3.0.1

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to figure out a solution but they intended to protect `DualListField` from developers change or behavior changes. The code is `Copyright(c) 2007-2012, Sencha, Inc.` so the following solution may not applied for commercial use.

You can either create your own `DualList` by copying the code and made the changes, or override their version by make the changes on a copy of `DualListField` then put the file in the same package structure to make it override the one in the JAR.

Copy the java file `DualListField` and paste it in a package named `com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.form` then remove all unwanted `IconButton` and compile and use it instead the original.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the DualListField and hide the buttons you want. Try this:

```
public class CustomDualListField<D extends ModelData> extends DualListField<D> {
    @Override
    protected void onRender(Element target, int index) {
        super.onRender(target, index);

        allRight.setVisible(false);
        up.setVisible(false);
        allLeft.setVisible(false);
        down.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using sencha gxt jar- 3.0.1 which does not contain the onRender method